# Why would a website only load with Safari (DNS timeout otherwise)?

Tags: docker, flask, safari, dns, digital-ocean

I am working on a web app on http://pagesage.page and have deployed with Digital Ocean on a Docker container with gunicorn and meinheld with A and AAAA name records set up.  Additionally, the appropriate ports for http have been set up for listening and responding.

Unfortunately, while the page responds to curl, ping, and ping6 requests, the page only ever loads on the Safari browser (and some IE distributions) and I can't seem to figure out why (I get DNS timeout errors whenever I try to load the page in Chrome or Firefox).

I've tried accessing the page from different machines (brand new and old), reset the DNS settings a few times, and reset the browser's cache, all with no success.

Does anyone have ideas or suggestions, or has anyone else encountered this same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a problem with your SSL/TLS terminaison. The website is available on HTTP but unavailable on HTTPS. Chrome and FF redirect the user to the HTTPS version. It looks like the port 443 (used for HTTPS) is closed.